# transition css, hace parpadear el background

Tags: css

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```css
#cajanumeral {
    height: 220px;
    margin:1em auto; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
    background-color: #0000ff;
  }
  #cajahijo:hover {
    box-shadow: 325px 0 #330000 inset;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #cajahijo{
    flex: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 #330000 inset;
    display: table-cell;margin: 0; padding: 0 1em;vertical-align: middle;font-size: 50px;color:#ffff00
  }
```

```html
<div id="cajanumeral" >
      <div id="cajahijo">
        37
      </div>
    </div>
```

Como verán el resultado al final de la transición  parpadea de forma horrible, ¿Como hago para que esto no suceda?

Comment: Pareciera interferir con algo, lo probé en un codepen y no parpadea, también lo probé en local e igualmente no apareció el «parpadeo».

Comment: @Shaz ,pero aqui en el foro te parpadea? o tampoco? el caso es que a mi, en mi pc si parpadea

Comment: Bueno, stackoverflow no es un foro... pero sí, aquí en stackoverflow sí parpadea.

Comment: en Chrome sí parpadea, en cambio en Firefox no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguio hacer lo que quieres sin que parpadee, en vez de jugar con la sombra de la caja, lo he hecho con el ancho de la caja hijo.

He cambiado los colores para diferenciar mejor las cajas

```css
    #cajanumeral {
        height: 220px;
        margin:1em auto; 
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: black;
       display:flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #cajahijo{
       border: solid red 1px;
        width:5%;
        height:100%;
       color: white;
       -webkit-transition: all 1s;
       background: red;
      }
      #cajanumeral:hover #cajahijo {
       width: 100%;
      }
     #vuela{
        //border: solid green 1px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 2$;
        color: white;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        font-size: 350%;
          margin-left: 18%;
     }
```

```html
    <div id="cajanumeral" >
         <div id="vuela">
           37
         </div>
          <div id="cajahijo">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Es similar y es buena pero quisiera que el rojo se despliegue cuando el mouse este en el color negro.

Comment: He editado la respuesta y he ajustado lo que decías, marca la respuesta como solucion o preguntame si hay algo que no te haya quedado claro. Salu2

Answer (score 2):

Es un bug de chrome que le ocurre a mucha gente. Lo más parecido a una solución, es añadirle un **0.01px** al box-shadow (ni idea de porque). Aun así de vez en cuando sigue ocurriendo, pero es mucho menor.

```css
#cajanumeral {
    height: 220px;
    margin:1em auto; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
    background-color: #0000ff;
  }
  #cajahijo:hover {
    box-shadow:325px 0 0 0 #330000 inset;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #cajahijo{
    flex: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    box-shadow:10px 0 0 0.01px #330000 inset;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 50px;
    color:#ffff00
  }
```

```html
<div id="cajanumeral" >
      <div id="cajahijo">
        37
      </div>
    </div>
```

Espero que te ayude, un saludo!

Comment: en caso de no haber otra solucion utilizare la tuya, pero esperare un poco mas haber si alguien sabe que pasa.